# Please prove If $x_1,x_2,x_3$,… is a sequence of distinct points in the closed interval [a,b], then the range of the sequence has a limit point.

Tags: real-analysis

I believe that I have come up with a good proof but would like some input on if there is anything that can be improved on thank you.

Question: If $x_1,x_2,x_3$,… is a sequence of distinct points in the closed interval [a,b], then the range of the sequence has a limit point.

Proof:

Let the closed interval [a,b] exist.

Let the sequence $\{x_n\}$= $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,.....,x_n\}$ exist such that it is a collection of distinct points in [a,b].

Then [a,b] would be bounded and  $\{x_n\}$ $\subset$ [a,b].

Then the range of $\{x_n\}$ is an infinite bounded set and we know that every infinite bounded set has a limit point.

Thus, the range of $\{x_n\}$ has a limit point.

Therefore, If $x_1,x_2,x_3,.....$ is a sequence of distinct points in the closed interval [a,b], then the range of the sequence has a limit point.

Answer (score 1):

*Let the sequence $\{x_{n}\}=\{x_{1},...,x_{n}\}$ exist*

This is unfathomable. I guess you were writing

Let $\mathcal{R}=\{x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n},...\}$ be the range of the sequence $\{x_{n}\}_{n}$.

You may want to show that $\mathcal{R}$ is infinite. It depends, this is almost obvious. But I would argue as the following:

Let $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathcal{R}$ be defined as $f:n\rightarrow x_{n}$, then $f$ is injective and so $|\mathbb{N}|\leq|\mathcal{R}|$ and hence $\mathcal{R}$ is infinite.